# Undefined property error while connectiong database using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

While Connection database through mysqli using php an error is showing at the bottom of the page

I am Hereby attaching the code

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="exam";
// Create the connection
$conn= new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
//Check Connection
if($conn->connection_error)
    {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

The **Error** Coming is

> Notice: Undefined property: mysqli::$connection_error in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\work\Cs\Admin-Panel\dbConnect_exam.php on line 9

Please Help!!!!

Comment: $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

Answer (score 6):

There is no `connection_error` property in mysqli. To check connection error use

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Comment: Nothing, my mistake. It was a property however, not a function or method.

Comment: Yes it's a property not a function!!

Comment: Really impress with your eagle eye!!

Comment: Anyways Thanks for your support!!

Answer (score 1):

You missepelled `connect_error` to `connection_error` [ `connection_error` is not a **PHP** property].Change it.Hope it will be worked.

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="exam";
    // Create the connection
    $conn= new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    //Check Connection
    if($conn->connect_error)
        {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: It's a property not a function and property does''t have `()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if($conn->connect_errno)
```

instead of

```
if($conn->connection_error)
```

Comment: Little explanation makes your answer better